# Find an HTML element which contains the largest number of mentions of given word

Tags: python, html, dom, html-parsing, cluster-analysis

I have an HTML document and I would like to find the HTML element which is the closest wrapper to the largest cluster of mentions of a given word.

With the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>
        Hello <b>foo</b>, I like foo, because foo is the best.
    <p>
    <div>
        <blockquote>
            <p><strong>Foo</strong> said: foo foo!</p>
            <p>Smurfs ate the last foo and turned blue. Foo!</p>
            <p>Foo foo.</p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like to have a function

```
find_largest_cluster_wrapper(html, word='foo')
```

...which would parse the DOM tree and return me `<blockquote>` element, because it contains the largest density of *foo* mentions and it is the closest wrapper.

The first `<p>` contains *foo* 3 times, the `<b>` only once, inner `<p>`s contain *foo* 3 times, twice and twice again, `<strong>` only once. But `<blockquote>` contains *foo* 4 times. So does the `<div>`, but it is not the closest wrapper. The `<body>` element has the highest number of mentions, but it is too sparse of a cluster.

Straightforward implementation without clustering would give me always `<html>` or `<body>` or something like that, because such elements always have the largest number of requested mentions and are probably the closest wrapper to them. However, I need something taking the largest cluster as I am interested only in the part of the web page with the highest density of the word.

I am not very curious about the parsing part, it could be well solved by `beautifulsoup4` or other libraries. I am wondering about an efficient algorithm to do the clustering. I googled for a while and I think [clustering package](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html) in `scipy` could be helpful, but I have no idea how to use it. Could anyone recommend me the best solution and kick me to the right direction? Examples would be totally awesome.

---

Well, it would be difficult to answer to such question in general, because the conditions are, as you pointed out, vague. So, more specifically:

Typically, the document will contain probably **only one such cluster**. My intention is to find such cluster and get it's wrapper so I can manipulate with it. The word could be mentioned also somewhere else on the page, but I am looking for a **notable** cluster of such words. If there are two notable clusters or more, then I have to use an external bias to decide (examine headers, title of the page, etc.). What does it mean the cluster is notable? It means precisely what I just presented - that there are no "serious" competitors. If a competitor is serious or not I could provide in some number (ratio), e.g. if there is cluster of 10 and cluster of 2, the difference would be 80%. I could say if there is a cluster with a difference larger than 50%, it would be the notable one. That means, if it would be cluster of 5 and another of 5, the function would return `None` (could not decide).

Comment: By the way, the problem seems quite vague, unless we have a way how to say that one cluster fits more than another. For example, if we have a node `<blockquote> ... </blockquote>` with quite high density of word `foo`. And this node is inside another div like this: `<div> <blockquote> ... </blockquote> foo foo foo</div>`. Which node shall we select? Blockquote or div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is an approach:

```
|fitness(node, word) = count of word in node text if node is a leaf
|fitness(node, word) = sum(fitness(child, word) for child in children) / 
                         count of overall elements in node tree
```

Here it is:

```
import lxml.html

node = """<html><body>
    <p>
        Hello <b>foo</b>, I like foo, because foo is the best.
    <p>
    <div>
        <blockquote>
            <p><strong>Foo</strong> said: foo foo!</p>
            <p>Smurfs ate the last foo and turned blue. Foo!</p>
            <p>Foo foo.</p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</body></html>"""

node = lxml.html.fromstring(node)

def suitability(node, word):
    mx = [0.0, None]
    _suitability(node, word, mx)
    return mx[1]

def _suitability(node, word, mx):

    children = node.getchildren()
    sparsity = 1
    result = float(node.text_content().lower().count(word))
    for child in children:
        res, spars = _suitability(child, word, mx)
        result += res
        sparsity += spars
    result /= sparsity
    current_max, max_node = mx
    if current_max < result:
        mx[0] = result
        mx[1] = node
    return result, sparsity

print suitability(node, 'foo')
```

It gives us blockquote element as the fittest. And by adjusting the score function you can change the parameters of desired cluster.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to return the max and node that has it (in addition to result and sparsity), rather than using a input list parameter as an implicit output parameter as well?

Comment: Yep, probably, but where to store the values? As a `node` attribute? I thought that it would be quite dirty.

Comment: Just return them from `_suitability` in addition to result and sparsity.

Comment: I finally used something in this manner, 'suitability' algorithm. I tested it on some sample data and it works like a charm. It cuts away for me exactly the container I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

So it's not a library, but I have an idea.

What if you build your parse tree of the HTML, and then annotate each node with two things:

1. The total number of words it contains.
2. The number of times it contains your target word.

Then you can search over your tree for a node which maximizes `target_count / total_count`.  This will give you your property of smallest containing element, since an element higher in the tree will contain more words.  In fact, what this does is give you the node with the highest density of the target word.

You may find that simple division doesn't give you quite the results you want.  For instance, if a node only contains one copy of your target word, it will have a very high density, but may not correspond to the notion of cluster you have in mind.  In this case, I would define some function that maps the number of words contained in an element to a size.  If you want to ensure the cluster is of a certain size, and to penalize clusters that are too large (e.g. `)<body>`)  that could be something like this:

```
def size(num_words):
   num_words = max(num_words, 40) # where 40 is the min size of a cluster
   if num_words > 1000: # This is too large, so we penalize
     num_words *= 1.5
   return num_words
```

Now you could do `target_count / size(total_count)`.

**Re: scipy clustering**

This clustering works on vectors.  So, in order to use this package, you're going to need to come up with a way of turning occurences of your target word into vectors.  I can't think of a good way to do this off the top of my head, but that doesn't mean no such way exists.

Answer (score 1):

The clustering package won't be of much help, because this is **not cluster analysis**.

It's more on the lines of **frequent pattern mining**, you might want to look into that instead.